# How can I display value labels just at the right of each bar in seaborn horizontal barplot in bold?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to put the value labels **bold** just **at the right of each horizontal bar** in a barplot with seaborn, but I cannot place them out of the bars and values are displayed in normal fontweight.

I've unsuccessfully tried tuning the few matplotlib.pyplot.text parameters, but I can't find the key to solve the problem.

This is the certain portion of code:

```
plt.figure()

ax = sb.barplot(x='count', y='location', data=plocat.iloc[:10,:], palette=('BrBG_r'))

ax.set_xlabel('Posted jobs per location')
ax.set_ylabel('')  # Remove y axis label
ax.set_xticklabels('')  # Remove x values

a = plt.gca()

for p in a.patches:
    a.text(p.get_width(), p.get_y() + p.get_height()/2., '%d' % int(p.get_width()), 
           fontsize=9, fontweight='bold', ha='right', va='center')

plt.box(on=None)  # Remove black frame
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('./imgs/toplocations.png', dpi=300)
```

The following URL shows the plot that I get: https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/5/13/f97b7ec0fc9a7eb951b42ed3b1de03b4-full.png

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you try `ha='left'` in `a.text`?

Comment: @SpghttCd my god... I tried every possible option, but I should have omitted that one at the time. Thank you! Do you know how to put the numeric values in bold style?

Comment: It should be simply a numeric value instead of some possible keywords like `bold`, see the related [docs](https://matplotlib.org/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text.set_fontweight). However, are you sure that `bold` did not work?  Perhaps it's just difficult to tell from `normal` at fontsize 9.

Comment: @SpghttCd I found the bug! When changing the default font (DejaVu Sans) to Futura, the modification in weight does not affect the text displayed. Thank you very much anyway. Your contribution was very useful